# How to convert xml file into mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, xml

I have an xml file which was created from a mysql database with just 1 table.
`<database_name>`
    `<table_name>`
        `<col1>row1</col1>`
        `<col2>row1</col1>`
    `</table_name>`
    `<table_name>`
        `<col1>row2</col1>`
        `<col2>row2</col2>`
    `</table_name>`
`</database_name>`
I need to convert this xml file back to a mysql database. How can I do this using Java?

Comment: If it just has one table, why does it have two table names? Isn't the easiest way to use a mysql client that can read XML?

Comment: **How** has it been created from a mysql database? If it was a tool, you may be able to use the very same tool for the other way round.

Comment: I agree, with @Andreas_D can you recreate this using msyqldump instead of this crazy xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xml parsing library like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html), to parse the file, loop through the results and emit a text file that contains a list of inserts.

Do you know the schema or does it need to be inferred from the data?

So your resultant text file would be something like

```
create table a ()

insert into a (c1,...cn) values (v1,...vn)
```

Then you could use mysqldump to push the file into a db

mysqldump -u [username] [databasename] < output.sql

Comment: The schema has to be inferred from the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can write XSL tranformation, and there is no need in Java